# Replace a part of string in big array with replace method and Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have array `String[] values = new String[100]`, and I need to check all strings from 10 to 35 with Java 8. Cause I don't want to do it with `if` and `else`.

For example:

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 35; i++){
    if (values[i].contains("something")) {
      values[i].replace("something", "something else");
    }
}
```

How can I do it with Java 8 and and small amount of code?

Help me please.

Comment: You don't ask a question here. What is the problem? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: how i can do it with java8 and and small amount of code row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach that might be a bit cleaner:

```
Arrays.asList(values).subList(10, 35 + 1)
      .replaceAll(s -> s.replace("something", "something else"));
```

NOTES:

- `subList()` takes a half-open interval, hence the second argument has `+1`.
- The result of `String.replace()` has to be assigned or returned, not thrown away, since of course it can't modify the original string.
- There's no point in calling `String.contains()` since that's implemented in terms of `String.indexOf()`. One of the first things `String.replace()` does is to call `String.indexOf()` and bail out if the string isn't found.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of this, but it's not any more readable or effective than what you already have in place:

```
 IntStream.rangeClosed(10, 35)
            .forEach(ix -> values[ix] = values[ix].replace("something", "something2"));
```

Comment: very very goog:)